# For in double map

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the double map

```
map <string, set <string>> a;
```

and want to output that map in lexicographical order. I try following code:

```
map <string, set <string>> a;    
for (auto pair = a.begin(); pair != a.end(); pair++) {
    cout << pair->first << " - ";
    for (auto value = pair->second->begin(); value != pair->second->end(); value++) {
        cout << *value << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

But this code does not work. I get the error that `pair` must have pointer type. What's wrong?

Comment: `pair->second.begin()`

Comment: `value != pair->second->end()`  -> `value != pair->second.end()`

Comment: `pair` is a bad name for an iterator and `->second` is not an iterator, but a reference.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use C++11... this should work:

```
map <string, set <string>> a;
for (auto & pair : a) {
    cout << pair.first << " - ";
    for (auto & value : pair.second) {
        cout << value << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (const auto& pair : a)` will avoid creating copies of the pairs.